# How does Damage Resistance and Successful Save interact?

Tags: dnd-5e, saving-throw, damage-resistance

In my campaign, I have a Barbarian with Primal Path of Bear totem. Bear totem gives damage resistance when raging.

During battle the barbarian is targeted by a breathe weapon. And makes his save for half damage. Does his damage resistance then kick in to halve the damage again?

My thinking is that the Successful save means he somehow managed to avoid half the impact of the attack. Then his damage resistance would kick in to halve the damage he did take. For example, the breath attack rolls 30 lightning damage. The successful save means he was only hit with 15 lightning damage. Then his Damage Resistance kicks in and he looses 7 HP.

Comment: Duplicates aren't inherently a bad thing. They generally do more good than harm so we prefer them to stick around since the difference in wording can often help broaden the search criteria (if that makes sense).

Comment: @PurpleMonkey -- it makes perfect sense

Comment: You logic train is spot on.